# JPanel won't paint correctly

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, geometry, paintcomponent

I am quite new to Java and Swing, and this is also my first post so sorry if it doesn't make too much sense.

What I am trying to do is when I click on a JPanel, I want it to add a circle where I click. At the moment, all that seems to happen is when I click, a small grey square appears inside the JPanel I want to add to, but I can't seem to find any way of making it draw as a circle.

I have a class that extends JPanel called "Ball" which is what is being added when I click.
At the moment, I am not too worried about it being in the correct location, just for it to draw the ball correctly.
Below is the code for my "Ball" class:

```
package paintsliders;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Ball extends JPanel{

private int x,y,w,h;

//I will use this constructor to put the ball in the correct location later.
Ball(){
    /*this.w = 100;
    this.h = 100;
    this.x = 200;
    this.y = 200;*/
}

//draw the ball
    @Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawOval(200,200,10,10);
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

}
```

I can kind of guess that it is something to do with the paintComponent method, but everywhere I have looked doesn't seem to have a solution for me.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5):

The `Graphcis` context has already been translated to meet the x/y location that the component should appear within it's parent container, this means that the top, left corner of the `Graphics` context within the `paintComponent` method is actually 0x0.

You need to define some size for the ball, you're painting at 10x10, which would suggest that your ball component should return a `preferredSize` of 10x10

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(10, 10);
}
```

You will become responsible for providing appropriate layout details to the ball when it's added to the parent container...

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
    Point p = evt.getPoint();
    Ball ball = new Ball();
    Dimension size = ball.getPreferredSize();
    ball.setBounds(new Rectangle(p, size));
    add(ball);
}
```

This, of course, assumes you have a `null` layout set for the parent container

**UPDATED**

Something like...

[image: See spot run]

```
public class PaintBalls {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PaintBalls();
    }

    public PaintBalls() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new Board());
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Board extends JPanel {

        public Board() {
            setLayout(null);
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    Point p = e.getPoint();
                    Ball ball = new Ball();
                    Dimension size = ball.getPreferredSize();
                    p.x -= size.width / 2;
                    p.y -= size.height / 2;

                    ball.setBounds(new Rectangle(p, size));
                    add(ball);
                    repaint();
                }

            });
        }

    }

    public class Ball extends JPanel {

        public Ball() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(10, 10);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillOval(0, 0, 10, 10);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I have implemented this and now it draws the object where I click, but how would I make it draw a circle instead of the rectangle?Sorry if this is really basic, but I really am new at this.

Comment: Try setting the `Ball` to transparent (`setOpaque(false)`)

Answer (score 4):

You probably have a main `JPanel` where you click.

I would rather design the main panel to handle the mouse click and the `Ball` class to be a simple `Object` that defines a `drawBall(Graphics g, int x, int y)` method that knows how to paint a `Ball`. This would be called by the `paintComponent()` method in the main panel. In the main panel, you handle the mouse click, create an object of type `Ball` and call `repaint()`. Inside the `paintComponent()` you call `ball.drawBall()`.